# Need to create a column in a dataset based on the value in a different dataset

Tags: sas, probability

I have a dataset that has a client id, and a uniform random variable for each id that looks something like this:

| ClientId | RandUnif |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 0.38223456 |
| 5678 | 0.7456789 |

*client ids are unique and serve as the primary key for this table

I then have another data set that has a “number of outcomes field” and a cumulative probability column that looks like this:

| NumOutcomes | CumulativeProb |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.543678 |
| 2 | 0.756789 |

My goal is to compare the uniform random variable from my client id table to the cumulative probability column in the second table in order to create a new column in the client table.

So, for instance the first row of the client table would have a value in the new column of “1” because it is less than our equal to the first cumulative probability. The second row would have a “2” in the new column because it’s greater than the first cumulative probability but less than the second, and so on.

I have tried using a do loop, and a sql query to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a cross-join where `RandomUnif <= CumulativeProb`. This would get you a table like this:

```
ClientID    NumOutcomes RandUnif    CumulativeProb
1234        1           0.38223456  0.543678
1234        2           0.38223456  0.756789
5678        2           0.7456789   0.756789
```

From there, you'll take the minimum value of `CumulativeProb` by each ClientID since the minimum value is less than or equal to the first cumulative probability. You can do this with a sql `having` clause.

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
        select ClientID
             , NumOutcomes
             , RandUnif
             , CumulativeProb
        from have, lookup
        where RandUnif LE CumulativeProb
        group by ClientID
        having CumulativeProb = min(CumulativeProb)
    ;
quit;
```

```
ClientID    NumOutcomes RandUnif    CumulativeProb
1234        1           0.38223456  0.543678
5678        2           0.7456789   0.756789
```

Comment: this worked like a charm! I ended up combining the two queries by putting the cross join in my from statement, but it does exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer from Stu this is what ended up working for me:

```
proc sql; 

create table output as

select clientid
, col2
, other_cols_needed
from (select *
      from client_table t1
      inner join cum_prob_table t2
      on t1.rand_unif <= t2.cumulative_probability)
group by clientid
having cumulative_probability = min(cumulative_probability); 

quit;
```

thanks again!